# One step yum install of java 1.7 in 32 bit with Linux

Tags: java, linux, yum

Previously I was installing java 1.7 in 32 bit format with the following

(notice the ftp insert)

```
yum install ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.4/updates/i386/Packages/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9-2.3.7.1.el6_3.i686.rpm
```

but now the install no longer works

```
[root@mmclntx ~]# yum install ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.4/updates/i386/Packages/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9-2.3.7.1.el6_3.i686.rpm
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Cannot open: ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.4/updates/i386/Packages/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9-2.3.7.1.el6_3.i686.rpm. Skipping.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@mmclntx ~]#
```

Is there a one step hum install command I can replace this with ?

Comment: Why would you use a 32-bit version on a modern machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
yum install  ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.5/os/i386/Packages/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.45-2.4.3.3.el6.i686.rpm
```

Result

```
Setting up Install Process
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.45-2.4.3.3.el6.i686.rpm                                                                               |  27 MB     00:02     
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-19c9mu/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.45-2.4.3.3.el6.i686.rpm: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.45-2.4.3.3.el6.i686
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-19c9mu/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.45-2.4.3.3.el6.i686.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-1.7.0-openjdk.i686 1:1.7.0.45-2.4.3.3.el6 will be installed
...
```

I'm missing something?

---

With JDK 1.7

```
# yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

OpenJDK is in default `updates` repository

```
Name        : java-1.7.0-openjdk
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.7.0.51
Release     : 2.4.4.1.el6_5
Size        : 26 M
Repo        : updates
Summary     : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
URL         : http://openjdk.java.net/
License     : ASL 1.1 and ASL 2.0 and GPL+ and GPLv2 and GPLv2 with exceptions and LGPL+ and LGPLv2 and MPLv1.0 and MPLv1.1 and Public Domain and W3C
Description : The OpenJDK runtime environment.
```

Comment: That is the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 1):

The installer does not work for a reason that is very clearly stated in the [README in directory index](ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.4/readme):

> This directory (and version of CentOS) is depreciated.  For normal
>   users, you should use /6/ and not /6.4/ in your path. Please see this
>   FAQ concerning the CentOS release scheme:
>
> http://www.centos.org/modules/smartfaq/faq.php?faqid=34
>
> If you know what you are doing, and absolutely want to remain at the
>   6.4 level, go to http://vault.centos.org/ for packages.
>
> Please keep in mind that 6.0, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3 and 6.4 no longer gets any
>   updates, nor any security fix's.

So, replace `/6.4/` with `/6/` in the FTP URL or go to `http://vault.centos.org` (whichever applies to your case) and you are set. Besides, the last line might be interesting for you :)

You should also consider getting the package from a repository, so that you will kept up-to-date with security fixes.

Comment: I tried that , but it did not work.  Did I do this correctly ?             yum install ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6/updates/i386/Packages/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9-2.3.7.1.el6_3.i686.rpm
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Cannot open: ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6/updates/i386/Packages/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9-2.3.7.1.el6_3.i686.rpm. Skipping

Comment: That's beacause the package has been updated. Try `yum install ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6/updates/i386/Packages/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51-2.4.4.1.el6_5.i686.rpm`.

Comment: Anyway, why just not use a repository (instead of downloading manually)?